# LongListSelector with ContextMenuService

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this `LongListSelector`:

```
<Controls:LongListSelector Height="Auto" x:Name="playlistList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="DidPressSelectItem"
                                       GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                       LayoutMode="List"
                                       IsGroupingEnabled="true" HideEmptyGroups="True">
              <Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SearchTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu Loaded="ContextMenu_Load" Unloaded="ContextMenu_Unload">
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                            <local:SearchTemplateSelector.Top100PlaylistTemplate>
                                  ........
                            </local:SearchTemplateSelector.Top100PlaylistTemplate>
                            <local:SearchTemplateSelector.PlaylistTemplate>
                                   ..............
                            </local:SearchTemplateSelector.PlaylistTemplate>
                         </local:SearchTemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>
              </Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </Controls:LongListSelector>
```

And i have a long press drop-down menu on every item, and i have also couple kind of `TemplateSelector`, and i want to be able to choose that the drop-down menu will work only in one of the Templates. how can i achieve it?

Comment: Can't you just add the contextmenu to the item inside you faux template selector?

Comment: It won't work if i put it inside